# Set timer and player count

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I saw this stream of this guy Timer (place where you have time is and the players pictures shows)and it was not up it was down on the screen , can i have the command to do it pls ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the game settings menu, then change Mini-Scoreboard Style to Bottom of Screen like so:

[image: mini-scoreboard style]